# How to move an image view to a specific point of a screen

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am developing a small game. I need to get the screen width and height and by comparing those values, I need to move the image view to specific positions of the screen. Is it possible to do so?? Please help

Thank you

Comment: U can but first describe what u tried so far.

Comment: Post code here, To know wat you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With little searching you can find many solutions to get all pieces you need to implement what you want:

For screen size: [Get screen dimensions in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions)

Drag and drop: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html

Bitmap drawing: [Android: Drawing Bitmap in Specific Location, Refusal to Draw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050996/android-drawing-bitmap-in-specific-location-refusal-to-draw)